# App Engine Cron Job Does Not Show Up After Uploading

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cron, gcloud, google-cloud-scheduler

I followed the [guide](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/scheduler/jobs/list) to create and upload a cron job for my GAE project. It looks like it works but does not show up in Cloud Scheduler. Here's the output when I run `gcloud app deploy cron.yaml`:

```
Configurations to update:

descriptor:      [/Users/me/Projects/org/prj-name/cron.yaml]
type:            [cron jobs]
target project:  [GCP-PROJECT-ID]


Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y

Updating config [cron]...⠹WARNING: We are using the App Engine app location (us-east1) as the default location. Please use the "--location" flag if you want to use a different location.
Updating config [cron]...⠶WARNING: We are using the App Engine app location (us-east1) as the default location. Please use the "--location" flag if you want to use a different location.
Updating config [cron]...done.                                                               

Cron jobs have been updated.

Visit the Cloud Platform Console Task Queues page to view your queues and cron jobs.
https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/taskqueues/cron?project=GCP-PROJECT-ID
```

The status code of that command is 0 and everything looks like it worked. However, if I then run `gcloud scheduler jobs list`, I get:

```
WARNING: We are using the App Engine app location (us-east1) as the default location. Please use the "--location" flag if you want to use a different location.
Listed 0 items.
```

I confirmed I have the latest gcloud version:

```
$ gcloud --version
Google Cloud SDK 421.0.0
bq 2.0.87
core 2023.03.03
gsutil 5.21

$ gcloud app update
Nothing to update.
```

Not sure if it's me but I tried simply copying and pasting the `cron.yaml` directly from the guide and even that didn't work, so I don't think so.

Comment: What is in your cron.yaml?  Maybe you have a typo.

Comment: I tried copying and pasting directly from Google documentation linked and also used a YAML linter, so it seems unlikely there's an issue with the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured it out. This is a case of terrible documentation and PEBKAC. There are 2 types of scheduled jobs:

1. App engine cron jobs
2. Cloud Scheduler jobs

The documentation I linked above tells you how to create type #1, app engine cron jobs. It then gives you a link, which directs you to "Manage your Cron jobs in Cloud Scheduler". This goes to jobs of type 2. There's another tab on that page to look at type 1 jobs however. Furthermore, from what I see, there's no gcloud app command to list jobs of type 1.

tl;dr: I was creating app engine cron jobs (#1) but then listing cloud scheduler jobs (#2) so of course there were none.

Comment: Oh also, as of 03/22/2023, the documentation mentions requests coming from IP address '0.1.0.2'. The place to look for that is the `x-appengine-user-ip` header, not the `x-forwarded-for` header as the former is the one that Google guarantees to strip away from external requests and insert its own.

Answer (score 0):

Try the command with the project flag i.e.

`gcloud scheduler jobs list --project=PROJECT_ID`

When you run gcloud commands without specifying a project, it either infers one (e.g a deploy will deploy all `yaml` files in your current folder) or it will use the current project i.e. the project that was set with `gcloud config set project PROJECTID`.

Comment: Forgot to mention I did try this with both the deploy as well as the list command with the same results.